# One Operation in C++

Tags: c++

I have been recently reading about space complexities of algorithms.

And I wondering how does C++ define "one operation"

So, `2+3 = 5` is treated as one operation or is it:

`2+3 = (010+ 011)b2 = (101)b2 =5`

And thus leading to 3 operations.

This question arises from the curiosity about bit shifting since it is more basic than the addition of multiple bits.
And having read that complexity of bit-shifting depends on the language used. I wanted to ask how does C++ define "one operation".

Comment: C++ doesn't really define anything like that. C++ has expressions, statements, etc. The expression `2+3` must evaluate to `5`, but that can happen in any way the implementation wants.

Comment: As far as I know typically in algorithmic time complexity analysis it's generally assumed that arithmetic operations on integers can be done in constant time because all values used will fit into some fixed-size representation known in advance, unless you're specifically looking at things like arbitrary-precision addition and multiplication where that assumption doesn't hold.

Comment: When you're talking about time- or space-complexity, what you're mostly interested in is the _thing_ that is being done repetitively with regards to how the number of _things_ grows in relation to the size of the task.  So for example when you consider the time complexity of a sorting algorithm, you're usually interested in how many comparisons are going to happen in relation to the number of items being sorted.  For space complexity, you're interested in how much storage is used relative to the storage of the original data.   Don't obsess over small detail: it's the growth trend that matters.

Comment: So, will there be no case where the complexity of the system differs due to any of the two aspects above?
Say, the complexity of "check if a number is a power of 2"  where both methods give a O(log n) complexity, one method is left bit shift and one being repeated division by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Different compilers or compiler options / optimisations can affect how such statements are handled, leading to there being no consistent definition of 'one operation' in c++. If you wanted to know how a particular piece of code is executed, you could put it into compilerexplorer/godbolt and setting the compiler & settings and looking at its assembly output.

That said, the 'number of operations' in this respect is not the point of consideration in algorithmic complexity for either time or space. They are defined it is in regards to the input of a function -  space complexity represents the amount of memory taken to perform the operation and time represents how long the function takes to execute. `3 + 5` would be represented as O(1) space  (and time, but that's not what you were asking about) complexity because the amount of memory taken to perform it is constant (2 or 3 registers usually, 2 inputs and an output, which depending on other considerations may be in the same or a different register).

Comment: So, depending on depending C++ compilers, the result will differ?

In a8051, we have pre-defined the number of cycles (and thus time and space occupied) for every instruction like SJMP, MOV so the same definitions cannot be extended to C++ ?

Comment: @Luce , this might be an interesting video for you by Herb Sutter in general related to this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lurOCdaj0Y&feature=youtu.be